# Finding the $x$-intercepts for $y= x^3-10x^2+31x-30$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you find the $x$-intercepts for this problem?

$$y= x^3-10x^2+31x-30$$

(Please show and explain how you solved it.)

Comment: In what context are you looking?  Is this your homework?  What have you tried?  What do you know or what are you currently learning?

Comment: It is on a homework assignment and I won't see the teacher until next week, so I needed help. I'm pretty sure that I have to factor it to solve for the intercepts, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Since it is on a homework assignment, there must be some context.  What are you studying?

Comment: The worksheet just says factoring cubic equations

Comment: What methods of factoring cubics have you learned?  Have you done division?  Do you know the rational root theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is this:  if $$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$ then you are looking to solve the following system.

$$r+s+t=a$$
$$rs+rt+st=b$$
$$rst=c$$

Should you find these $r,s,t$, these are your roots and your factored polynomial is just

$$(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)=0$$

However, not knowing these formulas is probably true.  In this case use the rational root theorem.  Test the possible rational roots (the factors of 30 in your case, $c$ in the general case) and then divide by the root or factor with long division or synthetic.

For your example, your possible rational roots are $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$.  You test both positive and negative factors.  You would find your first bit of luck with $2$ (the factor being $x-2$)...when you divide you will get a quotient of $x^2-8x+15$.  Then factor that.  See reckless reckoner's comment for further insight.

Comment: Descartes' Rule of Signs will cut down on the agony a bit.  There are three "sign changes" in the given polynomial, so either all three or just one of the possible rational zeroes are positive.  On the other hand, $ \ f(-x) \ $ , which is $ \ -x^3 \ - \ 10 \ x^2 \ - \ 31 \ x \ - 30 \ $ has no sign changes at all, so there are _no negative_ rational zeroes.

Comment: I opened Excel and entered "=+A1^3-10*A1^2+31*A1-30" into cell B1, and successively entered the factors of -30 into cell A1. I came up with the answer very quickly, with little agony. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Newton-Raphson method to find one root. That being done, long division yielded the remaining quadratic that could be easily factored.

With the Newton-Raphson method we make an initial guess $(x_0)$ and find the x-intercept $(x_1,0)$ of the line tangent to the curve at $(x_0, f(x_0))$. Then we repeat the process for $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$.

Given a general function $f$,
$$f'(x_k)=\frac{0-f(x_k)}{x_{k+1}-x_k}$$
or alternatively
$$x_{k+1} = x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$

In this particular case
$$x_{k+1} = x_k-\frac{{x_k}^3-10{x_k}^2+31x_k-30}{3{x_k}^2-20x_k+31}=\frac{2({x_k}^3-5{x_k}^2+15)}{3{x_k}^2-20x_k+31}$$

Using $x_0=0$ as the initial estimate, it only takes seven iterations to yield $x_6=1.999999707$, so I'm guessing that $x_{\infty}=2$.

Just to confirm though, $f(2)=2^3-10\cdot2^2+31\cdot2-30=8-40+62-30=0$

Comment: since he is precalculus, he doesn't have the option of using a derivative

Answer (score 0):

Since factoring a cubic directly is often difficult, the first step is to find a root using the Rational Root and Remainder Theorems.

The Rational Root Theorem states that if a polynomial

$$f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$$

has a rational root $p/q$, then $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and $q$ is a factor of $a_m$.  In your example

$$f(x) = x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 30$$

$a_0 = 30$ and $a_n = a_3 = 1$.  Thus, the possible rational roots are factors of $30$ divided by factors of $1$.  Since the only factors of $1$ are $\pm 1$, each of the possible rational roots is an integer, namely the factors of $30$.  They are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 6, \pm 15, \pm 30$.

The Remainder Theorem states that if $f(x)$ is divided by the linear factor $x - k$, then the remainder is $f(k)$.  In particular, if $f(k) = 0$, then $k$ is a root and $x - k$ is a factor.

In your example, the signs of the coefficients of the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 30$ alternate.  If we substitute a negative number for $x$, each of the terms will be negative.  Therefore, the root must be positive.

$$f(1) = 1 - 10 + 31 - 30 = -8$$

so $1$ is not a root and $x - 1$ is not a factor of $f(x)$.

$$f(2) = 8 - 40 + 62 - 30 = 0$$

Hence, $2$ is a root and $x - 2$ is a factor.  To find the other factor, you can use polynomial division or synthetic division.

The following method is a variation of polynomial long division.  Note that if we multiply $x - 2$ by $x^2$, we obtain $x^3 - 2x^2$.  We want the $x^3$ term, but we have added $-2x^2$ to the polynomial, so we must add $2x^2$ to balance the equation.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^3 - 10x^2 + 31x - 30\\
     & = x^2(x - 2) + 2x^2 - 10x^2 + 31x - 30\\
     & = x^2(x - 2) - 8x^2 + 31x - 30
\end{align*}
To obtain the $-8x^2$ term, we multiply $x - 2$ by $-8x$, which yields $-8x^2 + 16x$, so we must subtract $16x$ to balance the equation.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^2(x - 2) - 8x(x - 2) - 16x + 31x - 30\\
     & = x^2(x - 2) - 8x(x - 2) + 15x - 30\\
     & = x^2(x - 2) - 8x(x - 2) + 15(x - 2)\\
     & = (x^2 - 8x + 15)(x - 2)
\end{align*}
To find the remaining roots, solve the quadratic equation $x^2 - 8x + 15 = 0$.

Strategy:

1. Use the Rational Root and Remainder Theorems to find a rational root.  **Caveat:** Not every cubic has a rational root.  For instance, the real root of $x^3 - 2$ is the irrational number $\sqrt[3]{2}$.
2. Once you find a rational root $r$, divide the polynomial by $x - r$ using polynomial long division or synthetic division to find the quotient $q(x)$. Then $f(x) = (x - r)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial.
3. Find the remaining roots by setting the quadratic factor $q(x)$ equal to zero and solving the resulting quadratic equation.

The roots of the cubic are the $x$-intercepts of the graph.

Answer (score -2):

For X intercepts we have y=0 as shown in fig .You just have to findroots of polynomial .Thanks

[image]

Comment: You're actually writing these questions in your notebook? Must be new here...

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to see how to write mathematics here.